# Can I enter Romania, Bulgaria, Cyprus with a single-entry Croatian visa?

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, croatia

I'm a non-EU citizen who's going to travel to Croatia. If I'm planning to visit Romania, Bulgaria, Cyprus, or Serbia, would I need a multiple-entry visa or can I use a single entry Croatian visa?

Comment: Do you plan on exiting Croatia and returning? If so, that's multiple entries.

Comment: Aside from your original question, you are aware you will most likely also need a visa for the other countries? All of them are non-Schengen and Serbia is non-EU also.